# How can I get the DataKeyNames in aspx in codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I need to get the DataKeyNames in codebehind of my ASP.NET application (VB.NET). How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way (VB.NET code):

```
 For Each dkn As String in GridView1.DataKeyNames
     ' -- Do something here with dkn
 Next
```

`DataKeyNames` is an array of strings, so there can be more than one in a GridView. You can access the array members this way (example):

```
Dim FirstKeyName as String = GridView1.DataKeyNames(0)
```

Here is the [documentation on MSDN of the `DataKeyNames` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx).

Comment: I like VB.NET too and I use it often.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s As String = GridView1.DataKeyNames(0)
```